# is there any possible way to store current time only via phpmyadmin in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to store current time (for example 00:30) in one of my column , the default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` gives both date and time which i dont want.

or is there any way of retrieving only time from `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ??

Comment: use TIME() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time `SELECT *, TIME(date-stamp-field) as time ...`

Comment: unlikely to havee anything to do with phpmyadmin, which is just a another db management script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's built-in [`TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function to extract the time part of a datetime expression. For example:

```
mysql> select time(now());
+-------------+
| time(now()) |
+-------------+
| 18:21:38    |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Since [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) is a synonym for `NOW()`, you can just use `TIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try combining `TIME()` and `NOW()`:

```
SELECT TIME(NOW());
```

Output: `15:20:31`

Of course, your column will need to be of type "[TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html)".

Answer (score 0):

When you create the table set the column type to `TIME`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you have a timestamp column that has a default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
  ...,
  ...,
  currentTime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

If you just want to store the current time, and not the date part, you could use a TIME column and trigger, that will insert the time part automatically:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (
  ...,
  ...,
  currentTime TIME
);

CREATE TRIGGER currentTime BEFORE INSERT ON tableName
FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.currentTime = TIME(NOW());
```

(an example is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c85c36/1)) and you might also want to use an UPDATE trigger. Or you can just use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and get only the time part with TIME function:

```
SELECT TIME(yourTimestampColumn)
FROM yourTable
```